# Python Selenium send_keys time interval

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to **scrape** some info from a website, but sometimes it's tricky cause continuous searching make the website able to detect the non-manual process, so I wanna input a time function to do seach like two search a time, then ten mins later, the second batch of seaching(the next two), but do not know how to use that func, my code like:

```
def get_keyword():
    data = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx')
    for d in data['name']:
        search(d)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('in progress')
    get_keyword()
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: `implicitly_wait` is only for waiting for element in HTML, not for pausing code. You have to use `time.sleep()` for this.

Comment: if you want to wait 10 minutes then maybe you should use external programs (scheduler) to execute script every 10 minuts. On Linux you can use `cron` for this.

Comment: btw; you can use `browser.implicitly_wait(10)` once and it will remeber this value.

Comment: @furas, thanks for your help, ```implicitly_wait``` is used for website respond, time.sleep does not work well when I put after get_keyword func

Comment: you have to use it after `search(d)` - inside `for`-loop. OR inside `search()` . It will create pause after every search. If you want to pause after two search then you will have use variable to count loops and when it is 2 then run sleep and reset count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make pause after every search then you should use `time.sleep` after `search(d)`

```
import time

def get_keyword():
    data = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx')
    for d in data['name']:
        search(d)
        time.sleep(10*60) # 10min * 60s
```

If you want to make pause after every two searches then you have to count loops. And when you count to 2 then run `time.sleep` and reset counter.

```
import time

def get_keyword():
    data = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx')

    count_loops = 0

    for d in data['name']:
        search(d)

        count_loops += 1
        if count_loops == 2:
            time.sleep(10*60) # 10min * 60s
            count_loops = 0
```

If it has to behave more like human then you should use random time

```
import time
import random


        if count_loops == 2:
            minutes = random.randint(8, 12)  # 8-12 minutes

            time.sleep(minutes*60)
            count_loops = 0
```

If you will countdown from 2 to 0 then you could even use random number of searches

```
import time
import random

def get_keyword():
    data = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx')

    count_loops = random.randint(1, 4)

    for d in data['name']:
        search(d)

        count_loops -= 1

        if count_loops == 0:
            minutes = random.randint(8, 12)  # 8-12 minutes
            time.sleep(minutes*60) # 10min * 60s

            count_loops = random.randint(1, 4)
```

Comment: got it, really helps a lot! thank you so much for your help : )!

Answer (score 0):

The sleep function is really easy, first you need to import this

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

The following code meaning the program will suspend for 5 seconds. Put this line at the place you want to stop. Also you can change the seconds for suspending.

Comment: thanks for your help! I put it after get_keyword func, but it still continuously working..